# How do I solve osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0) issue?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jbossfuse

[Getting this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NniQ.png)I have included some codes from my pom.xml . I have installed geronimo 1.1 jms spec but that didn't solve the problem at all. I am getting the dependency issue for some reason.  I am not using any of the javax.jms 1.1 dependencies in my pom but osgi keeps on asking for it. I have searched my solutions in redhat but no avail.

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.ups.ttg.ao.fuse</groupId>
<artifactId>foi-ao-acars-request</artifactId>
<version>3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>foi-ao-acars-request</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.redhat-377</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ups.ttg.ao.fuse</groupId>
        <artifactId>foi-ao-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring3</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/ADLB</schemaIncludes>
                <schemaIncludes>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/TWC</schemaIncludes>
                <!-- <bindingFiles>bindings.xml</bindingFiles> -->
                <extension>true</extension>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>com.ups.ttg.ao.fuse.acarsrequest</Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*,org.apache.camel.osgi;resolution:=optional, javax.jms; version=[1.1.0,3)</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
                <instructions>
                    <manifestLocation>src/main/resources/META-INF</manifestLocation>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>*,org.apache.log4j</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- the spring context file must be separate from the OSGi bundle, 
                    so we provide one here -->
                <fileApplicationContextUri>src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml</fileApplicationContextUri>
                <logClasspath>true</logClasspath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you list should include the the bundle that is complaining.  The dependencies listed in your pom.xml file require JMS 2.0.1.  I suspect that it is one of your bundles that needs JMS 1.0.  You can use the `list` command at the karaf prompt and the `headers` and `imports` commands to look at the bundles requirements.

JBoss Fuse 6.3 includes ActiveMQ 5, which technically is a JMS 1.0 implementation. The JMS specification bundle included with JBoss Fuse 6.3 does not list JMS 1.0 as supported, only JMS 2.  Seeing as the JMS 2 specification specifically states that all JMS 2 implementations must support JMS 1 applications without modification, I feel that this is an oversight.

So, what you have in JBoss Fuse is an ActiveMQ version that only supports JMS 1.  The JMS API version that is included in JBoss Fuse lists only JMS 2.  This was done to support IBM MQ 8 and greater that require JMS 2.  Even though IBM MQ 8 and 9 say that they need JMS 2, however, the actual IBM client code only uses JMS 1.

The bottom line is, determine which bundle is requiring JMS 1 and change the bundle manifest file to say that the bundle can use JMS 2.